# using a variable as speed indicator for .animate

Tags: jquery

I want the user to select the animation time with a dropdown menu, I´v tried for a few hours now, but it doesn´t work right. I´m new to jQuery, so maybe someone can help me with my problem and describe the mistake to me. Thanks in advance

When my code is like this, the value is posted right to the variable, but I think, somehow a .on('change') is missing, but I don´t really now where.

This is my jQuery Setup:

```
$(function() {
    $('#engage').bind('click',function(event){
      var speed = $('#sol').val();            
      var $anchor = $(this);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollLeft: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().left
        }, speed);
        event.preventDefault();
        alert(speed);
    });
});
```

This is my HTML Setup:

```
    <form id="speed">
    <label for="sol">Speed</label>
    <select name="sol" id="sol" style="display:none;">
        <option value="1000">1000</option>
        <option value="2000">2000</option>
        <option value="4000">4000</option>
        <option value="8000">8000</option>
        <option value="16000">16000</option>
        <option value="25000">25000</option>
        <option value="50000">50000</option>
        <option value="100000">100000</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Post a link to a jsfiddle please.

Comment: With your code, the dropdown is not even showing. here is a jfiddle where it shows: http://jsfiddle.net/jrm2k6/XS2dH/

Comment: I think an .on('change') is missing, because the value is posted to the value, but nothing changes in the animation speed. When the variable looks like var speed = 20000; everything works fine

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `()` after the `.val` to make it execute..
(* and the `$` at the beginning*)

Use

```
var speed = $('#sol').val();
```

Answer (score 1):

check out this line

```
var speed = ('#sol').val();
```

you forgot to use $  sign other seems to be fine.